# Async task waiting for another task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I have code like :

```
private async Task<bool> DoAsyncThing()
{
  await doOtherThings();
} 

private async Task<bool> DoAsyncThing2()
{
  await doOtherThings2();
} 

private async Task<bool> SaveAll()
{
   return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}

public async Task<bool> FirstBatchProcess()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
    ...
    users.Foreach(user => {
        task.Add(this.DoAsyncThing());
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return await this.SaveAll();
}

public async Task<bool> SecondBatchProcess()
{
    // get all data from batch 1 and then do calculation
    var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
    ...
    users.Foreach(user => {
        task.Add(this.DoAsyncThing2());
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return await this.SaveAll();
}


public async Task<bool> ProcessAll()
{
    await this.FirstBatchProcess();
    await this.SecondBatchProcess();
}
```

In the ProcessAll I want firstBatchProcess to be done first before doing SecondBatchProcess. Because I have some data from FirstBatchPRocess to be used later in SecondBatchProcess. If I run this code, both will be executed async and caused error because the SecondBatchProcess required the data generated from FirstBatchProcess.

note: both BatchProcesses contains multiple async loop so I use Task.WhenAll()
How to wait FirstBatchProcess finished then executed SecondBatchProcess ?

Comment: All tasks have completed `WhenAll` tasks are completed, can you be a bit more concise as its unclear what you exactly want

Comment: What's happening that shouldn't, or not happening that should?

Comment: As it is, `this.SaveAll()` will be called after `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` finishes

Comment: I just need to know if the Task.WhenAll() done so I can executed another tasks.
I have 2 batches tasks, the second one require the first one finished first.

Comment: Well, `this.SaveAll()` won't happen until `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` completes. It sounds like you already have what you want. Do you have reason to think that `SaveAll()` is happening too soon?

Comment: But you could look into the use of the [Task.Wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, if you want execution to pause until `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` is finished running.

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` will wait the task completed, I think you have got what you want. You can also do it more clearly like this `await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(()=>SaveAll())`.

Comment: so when I call Task.Wait() it will waiting this task to be done then it will continue another process ?

Comment: @nightingale2k1 if you use `Task.Wait()` it will most likely deadlock... and never continue...

Comment: @nightingale2k1 is your question (after edits) just "will `await` wait till task complete"?

Comment: I have this sinking feeling, that this will become a never ending tutorial on async await.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

> so when I call Task.Wait() it will waiting this task to be done then
>   it will continue another process ?

Since you edited your question, and if i understand you correctly (i'm reading between the lines)

```
await this.FirstBatchProcess();  // will wait for this to finish
await this.SecondBatchProcess(); // will wait for this to finish
```

The answer is yes all tasks started in `FirstBatchProcess` will complete before it executes `SecondBatchProcess`

**Original**

[Task.WhenAll Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates a task that **will complete when all of the supplied tasks have
>   completed**.

I think you maybe getting confused with the `await` operator

[await (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await)

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to
>   insert a suspension point in the execution of the method **until the
>   awaited task completes**. The task represents ongoing work.

It actually waits!

[**Your Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P5qTQD)

```
private static async Task DoAsyncThing()
{
    Console.WriteLine("waiting");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("waited");
}

private static async Task SaveAll()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Saving");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

public static async Task ProcessAll()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(DoAsyncThing());
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    await SaveAll();
    Console.WriteLine("Saved");
}

public static void Main()
{
    ProcessAll().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("sdf");
}
```

**Output**

```
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waited
waited
waited
waited
waited
waited
waited
waited
waited
waited
Saving
Saved
sdf
```

All tasks were completed.

Comment: I would have expected the comments more mixed for example `waiting,waiting,waited,waiting,waited...` etc

Comment: @EmrahSüngü remembering a thread maybe the original thread when calling `Console.WriteLine("waiting");` its only when the await is hit, that things may or may not start to happen

Comment: i see i see, I also think the core numbers will also have an effect right? Also the time it takes to actually finish the task etc

Comment: @EmrahSüngü when the task scheduler is diving out threads from the threadpool yes. however in certain situations (especially io situations) with the async await pattern, not so much

Comment: I just did a simple test! Increasing the number of tasks and decreasing the Delay time, I could get a mixture of outputs! Thanks

Comment: @EmrahSüngü yup, also if you did a async ping with a 1 second timeout to a dead address, you could probably load up 100 and possibly a lot more, without worrying about the thread pool delay. The reason why is it will be waiting for completion ports and not tying up non io threads. which one of the awesome scalable advantages of async await

Comment: @EmrahSüngü try this example https://dotnetfiddle.net/ClvgRg (obviously it wont work on .net fiddle) as they dont want to DOS people. pump the count up

Comment: thanks for the demo. yes I was confused with await, now I have clear understanding

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Task.Factory.StartNew();`

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     return DoAsyncThing();
}).ContinueWith(x =>
{
     if (x.Result)
        SaveAll();
});
```

if `DoAsyncThing()` do something with UI, you should use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` with `StartNew()`

I hope it helps.

Thank you.